# Google Cloud Vision API, identifying a snake in long grass

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, vision-api

When I run the following image through the Google Cloud Vision API it see's the grass but not the snake. What can I do to improve object detection?

[image: Snake in long grass]

Answer (score 1):

We can improve image detection by following the [recommended image size guidelines](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/supported-files) or by using [crop hints](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-crop-hints) to make the snake more dominant in the image. Google Cloud Vision API is powered by machine learning and misses like this (snake) is expected on the early stages of the API. [Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) improves over time as new concepts are introduced and accuracy is improved.

Sample use of crop hints: 
[image]

Result show "60% reptile" when using the [Vision API explorer](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/drag-and-drop):

Comment: This is just a copypasta answer with nothing relevant to specific question.

Comment: I added an example of using [crop hints](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-crop-hints) to improve image detection.